# can we add multiple rows to existing table in word template using java

Tags: java, ms-word, word-template

I have a Word template including a table (3 columns and one row).   I want to add more rows to this table using any API in Java. Can I add additional rows to an existing table in Word 2010 template?

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Apache POI found here https://poi.apache.org/ but this may be a bit tricky unless you are using excel.

Another option is the Aspose APIs found here http://www.aspose.com/

This code would add a row to an existing table

```
  Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "document.docx");
  // Retrieve the first table in the document.
  Table table = (Table)doc.getChild(NodeType.TABLE, 0, true);
  // Clone the last row in the table.
  Row clonedRow = (Row)table.getLastRow().deepClone(true);
  // Remove all content from the cloned row's cells. This makes the row ready for
  // new content to be inserted into.
  for (Cell cell: clonedRow.getCells())
{    
       cell.getFirstParagraph().getRuns().clear();
       cell.getFirstParagraph().appendChild(new Run(doc,"hello text"));
}
// Add the row to the end of the table.
table.appendChild(clonedRow);

doc.save(MyDir + "Table.AddCloneRowToTable Out.doc");
```

Ref: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/648997/reg-adding-rows-dynamically-to-the-existing-table-in-the-document.aspx

Comment: Using Apache POI iam able to create table but my requirement is to add rows to existing table.can you share with example.

Comment: I tried with above example,i'm able to add only one row.